# Character Idle animation

Tags: python, pygame

I was trying to get my idle animation to work for pygame but the error I get is argument 1 must be pygame.surface, not list.

Problem is that im trying to load in different images in my file but for reasons beyond my understanding it does not work.
the line tht im having trouble with is *screen.blit(champion, (playerX, playerY)*
what does this mean?

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

bg = pygame.image.load('Sandy.png')
champion = [pygame.image.load("Champion 1.png"), pygame.image.load("Champion 2.png"),
            pygame.image.load("Champion 3.png")]
playerX = 50
playerY = 50
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

isJump = False
jumpCount = 10

left = False
right = False
walkCount = 0


def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    if walkCount + 1 >= 30:
        walkCount = 0
    else:
        screen.blit(champion, (playerX, playerY))
        walkCount = 0
    pygame.display.update()


running = True

while running:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and playerX > vel:
        playerX -= vel
        left = True
        right = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and playerX < 500 - vel - width:
        playerX += vel
        left = False
        right = True

    else:
        left = False
        right = False
        walkCount = 0

    if not isJump:
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
            left = False
            right = False
            walkCount = 0

    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            playerY -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            jumpCount = 10
            isJump = False

    redrawGameWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument of [`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) must be a *Surface*, but not a list of *Surfaces*:

<s>`screen.blit(champion, (playerX, playerY))`</s>

```py
screen.blit(champion[walkCount], (playerX, playerY))
```

`redrawGameWindow` function:

```py
def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    frameCount = 2
    if walkCount // frameCount >= len(champion):
        walkCount = 0
    screen.blit(champion[walkCount // frameCount], (playerX, playerY))
    walkCount += 1

    pygame.display.update()
```

If you want an "idle" animation, you have to remove `walkCount = 0` from the application loop.

Comment: and replace it with frameCount? it expects an indent

Comment: @Zak All you have to do is to copy the `redrawGameWindow` function.